# What is the purpose of the Winlogon\LeakTrack registry key?

Tags: registry

Whats the purpose of this registry key?

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WINDOWS NT\CURRENTVERSION\Winlogon\LeakTrack
```

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: I am busy programming a system state backup solution and this registry key popped up in my research and I can't seem to find any documentation on it so I figured some of the seasoned system programmers on SO would know, so yes its a programming question (to me at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This key has do with the registry handle leak tracking functionality within Windows. It has the following spec:

```
Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
Name: LeakTrack
Type: REG_DWORD
Data: 0 or 1
```

If LeakTrack is set to 1 (one), Windows tracks all open registry keys and detect 
if any are leaked. This registry key is not required for normal operating 
system functionality.

The functions in ADVAPI32.dll (the registry API) responsible for getting a 
registry key handle read this value.  When the value is set 
appropriately they collect a call stack whenever they are asked to 
get a registry key under the user profile hives.  Later when the registry 
keys are release closed it removes the discards the collected call stack 
information.

It is needed only for debug sessions when memory leaks are to be tracked.
The value is set by Microsofts UPHClean (User Profile Hive Cleanup Service ) 
service for example.